# Choose an app to boot on android startup

Tags: android, startup, boot

I'm writing a setup manager application, from which the user will be able to specify certain settings unique to their android-powered device. My task is to provide a way for end users to choose, by clicking a button in this app, what application they want to start as soon as the device boots up.

It seems simple enough to make my own app start on boot with a broadcast receiver and service, but I want to control other apps through a setting in my own app. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried starting the other app when your app receives the boot event?

Comment: That worked perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Register a BOOT_COMPLETE receiver so your app (or service) can be launched when boot up. Then, trigger the other apps you selected by the intent and the package name, which you got when you list them out via PackageManager.